# function that returns second element of a stack without altering the stack in C++

Tags: c++, stack

I am thinking that the best way to return the second element of a stack without popping the stack is to create a function is to uses peek but peek returns the top element. How would I override peek so that it returned the second element, or use peek in some other fashion to accomplish my goal?

Comment: "Stack" is abstract data type. If you want concrete answer - show what implementation of stack you trying to change OR explain that you trying to implement generic "peek(n)" method that work on abstract stack that have just "push" and "pop"...

Comment: create another stack to hold all element above second one. after that take value of second element and then pop element from second stack and put back to original stack

Comment: A stack should only support operations at head and tail. If you want to take the second element, you need more than a stack. Since you are tagging it with `c++`, I'd suggest you use `std::deque` directly. `std::stack` is just a wrapper upon it by default.

Comment: Do you need to be standard conformant? If not I'd bet you that the elements are close to each other in memory, that is, close to `&top`. The second to last element could be at `&top-1`.

Answer (score 1):

This is java like pseudo algorithm. What you do is use a variable to store the top of the stack (pop if it exists), use another to store the second element of the stack (peek if it exists), push the top element back and then return the second element.

```
Object obj = stack.empty() ? null : stack.pop();
if(obj == null)
    return null;
Object ret = stack.empty() ? null : stack.peek();
stack.push(obj);
return ret;
```

But everything depends on how the stack is implemented. In C++, you'll have to do something like this.

```
if(stck.size() < 2) throw "Stack has no second element!";
Object obj = stck.top();
stck.pop();
Object ret = stck.top();
stack.push(obj);
return ret
```

Comment: I want to first thank all of you who have contributed to this post. This was an exercise posed in my C++ book by Tony Gaddis. the best ideal I could come up with is to alter this copy stack fucnction so that it would Cout the second element as it copies the first stack then destroys the copy it makes to clean up

Comment: template <class Type> void stackType<Type>::copyStack(const stackType<Type>& otherStack)
{
 delete[] list; 
 maxStackSize = otherStack.maxStackSize; 
 stackTop = otherStack.stackTop; 
 
 list = new Type[maxStackSize]; 
 //copy otherStack into this stack 
 for (int j = 0; j < stackTop; j++) list[j] = otherStack.list[j];
} //end copyStack

Comment: I am sorry I dont know how to format my code here are the two lines i added that i would hope make fulfill the goal: for (int i = 0; i < stackTop; i++)
  cout << "the second element is:::" << i + ;
 list = null;

Comment: @Darnell What you're trying to achieve is at this point unknown. The header of your question slightly contradicts the body. Can you make your question as clear as possible both in the header and the body?

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ Standard `std::stack` contains a protected member variable for the container named `c`. Knowing this and using a little bit of magic you can gain access to it with a pointer to this member variable. Once you have access to the underlying container (`std::deque` by default) you can access the contained data.

```
template<class T /* value type */, class C /* container */>
typename std::stack<T, C>::container_type& GetContainer(std::stack<T,C>& adapter)
{
    struct AdapterAccessor : std::stack<T, C>
    {
        static std::stack<T, C>::container_type& Get(std::stack<T, C>& adapter)
        {
            return adapter.*&AdapterAccessor::c;
        }
    };

    return AdapterAccessor::Get(adapter);
}
```

This works because although `AdapterAccessor` does not have direct access to the contents of `adapters` it does have indirect access via the pointer-to-member.

You can also make it usable with other container adapters.

```
template <template<class, class> class Adapter, class T, class... Args>
typename Adapter<T, Args...>::container_type&
GetContainer(Adapter<T, Args...>& adapter)
{
    struct AdapterAccessor : Adapter<T, Args...>
    {
        static Adapter<T, Args...>::container_type& Get(Adapter<T, Args...>& adapter)
        {
            return adapter.*&AdapterAccessor::c;
        }
    };

    return AdapterAccessor::Get(adapter);
}
```

Example usage:

```
int main()
{
    std::stack<char> st;
    st.push('1');
    st.push('2');
    st.push('3');
    st.push('4');

    auto& contents = GetContainer(st);
    std::cout << contents[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << contents[3] << std::endl;
    std::cout << contents[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << contents[2] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is possible, since a stack is based off of the principle last in first out.  All you have is a pointer to the stack, and from there you can pop off from the top of the stack, but you cannot pop off within the stack.  The only way I can think of to do it would be to create a function like.

```
object returnSecond(stack<object> a){
 a.pop();
 return a.top();
}
```

or a more general one function like

```
object peekN(stack<object> a, int n){
 for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
  a.pop();
 }
return a.top();
}
```

Comment: +0: possible start... please check out title of the post "without altering the stack" - clearly your code is not enough to satisfy that.

Comment: It shouldn't alter the stack since you are creating a local stack in the function and shouldn't affect the stack being used.  You could also push the popped values onto a new stack and when you get the value you want, repopulate your original stack.

Comment: Sorry missed that you make copy... now `peek2` is O(n) instead of O(1)... definitely a solution but I don't think it is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Not to be restricted in "Stack". It is an abstract datatype, so you can define the datatype of yourself. If you just don't want to define datatype and want to use some functions of stack. I  advise you to define a function of yourself(like the answer of Sudo Andrew). But it seems far-fetched and not like stack.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < stackTop; i++) cout << "the second element is:::" << i + ; list = null;

Answer (score 0):

just use std::vector instead.

```
std::vector<int>numbers;

numbers.push_back(1);
numbers.push_back(2);
numbers.push_back(3);

int secondElem = *(nums.end() - 2);

cout << secondElem << endl;
```

prints 2